# Is the phrase "let happen whatever may" valid and correct in the sense of leaving something to chance?

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

Is the phrase *let happen whatever may* valid and correct in the sense of leaving something to chance For example:

> I have not idea what is going to come up in the exam. I have no time to prepare, so **let happen whatever may**.

If it doesn't sound natural, what would you say?

Comment: Ironically, that part of the sentence is the most natural. *I have **no** idea what is going to **be on** the exam. I have **no** time to prepare.* As for the actual question, the phrase is uncommon and poetic, but still actually grammatical. I can think of several ways of rephrasing it, but they all either at least subtly change the meaning or are not as succinct.

Comment: @JasonBassford I think in the UK _come up in the exam_ is frequently heard.